# How to remove these negative tag score from my profile?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I have a positive or non negative score for every answer I gave. But once I got down voted for an answer but now it's positive and neutral. Here is an image of my account that I want to make changes

[image: this is the status]

Comment: You can remove them by answering questions in those tags and getting upvotes.

Comment: Is that an alt account of yours? The one you have here is associated with a main site account that doesn't have those tags. Besides, questions and answers you have posted are public information - blanking out their titles is simply futile whether they are yours or someone else's.

Comment: Ah, [you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3106424/optimuskck), @BoltClock. Why, user3134016? (And why not respond to BoltClock's comment? And why [answer your own question with a different account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770561/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-a-code/20770979#20770979)? We don't like sock puppets.)

Comment: But then, [this made me smile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EFKJv.png), so happy holidays to you ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: I hope your questions for him were as rhetorical as mine.

Comment: (Ah, you fooled me there, @BoltClock! `:-)`)

Comment: @Arjan: Well it works both ways, if my questions were genuine then yours should ideally be as well ;)

Answer (score 7):

Tag scores are only updated once a day, they are not dynamic. All you have to do to see the correct scores is to way until the appropriate script runs on the backend (3am UTC I believe).

There's nothing else you can or should do about it, except posting other good questions and answers in those tags, or improving the ones you already made, to get the tag scores into the positives.